# Buddypress error 404 page not found in members area

Tags: buddypress

I had created project management in buddypress, every thing working fine but getting 404 error while clicking on link of tasks in projects.

**What may be the reason for this ?**

here is the website url : http://joinup.co

Login url :http://joinup.co/wp-login.php

**Username** : demo

**Password** : demo

Link for task and project page

https://joinup.co/members/demo/projects/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no visible project links in the url you provide. 
There is a link to `/projects/project`. 
But that link is not found because it is relative. 
You need absolute urls.
Here is an example of adding tabs & screens in the profile area:
https://gist.github.com/shanebp/5d3d2f298727a0a036e5